# Single signon with Microsoft Outlook Webmail

Tags: 7, rating, authentication-authorization

I am using Drupal 7. I wanted to create Intranet pages where staff/employees can log in with their credentials. Is there any way so that they can log in with their https://login.microsoftonline.com/ login individual account?

I know [OAuth Connector Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauthconnector), [HybridAuth Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) are used for Twitter, Linked In, or Google connectors, but I am looking for a module which can connect with Microsoft Outlook Webmail.

Comment: I think this is a server side thing. You need to install and configure a mail client on your server. I did this a long time ago. It's a pain the ...

Comment: @No Sssweat - If you know, can you please give me more details about it.

Comment: you need to install postfix and dovecot. Here is a tutorial http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/ edit: This tutorial is for Ubuntu, so if your server is running on something else the command lines might not work for you.

Comment: I have not seen a module that already does this, you can build your own using Office365 API's ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/rest-api-overview ) and alternatively use a service like Auth0 (https://auth0.com/). I have not used it myself but have heard good things about it.